# how can Syrian user use an app has Firebase features without using a vpn?

Tags: java, android, firebase, vpn

I built my android app using Firebase features, authenticating, database, push notifications.
the problem is, Syrian users can't use these features unless they run a VPN app first.

the app keeps showing them the message in the picture. Error 403 forbidden.
but after running the vpn, all the features run successfully, log in, sign up, getting the data from database.etc ...

is there any solution where the user can use these features without running a vpn?

thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a [known issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Syria). You could try sending a [sternly worded letter](https://www.state.gov/syria-sanctions/). I'd suggest running a vpn at all times. Maybe two.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , do you think there is an alternative , another server where it runs on all countries without any problem?

Comment: could you use something like tor? your question doesnt go into massive detail

Comment: @Owensteam I don't know what to tell you, I built the app, and when i test it, for example trying the log in or sign up, it won't work until i run a vpn first it shows me Error 403 forbidden, after running a vpn, i can log in successfully. the same goes for the rest of features my app has.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking there is some kind of government proxy for this traffic which is why it isn’t working for Syrian users?

Comment: @Owensteam it's a possibility, but i don't think so.

Comment: The response you get shows that google has forbidden this service on Syria, like almost every internet service in the world due to the unfair sanctions of USA on Syria. I hope they remove these sanctions on the poor country and its people because they make their lives harder.

Comment: if you find a practical solution please update the thread with the solution.
 regards

Comment: @omar Unfortunately I did not find a solution, maybe the simplest way is to forgot countries like this one.

Comment: @Owensteam It's rather based upon US export regulations (this is not China), which means that US corporations may offer geo-targeted services and can decide who (where) may use them. Israel does not really follow these sanctions, but had them long before already; it may be working in the Golan Heights, when someone would run a cable across the border-line - or use Cellcom network near the border-line; both would be strictly illegal (under military law, not civil law) and not to be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that all google development features are banned in Syria, Iran, Sudan and North Korea....

The solution is to try another database hosting.... I think it's available as SQL database only